# Accidentally deleted all IAM users, now getting permission error while creating private service connection with GCP

Tags: automation, devops, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-ops-agent

I have accidentally deleted all IAM users while applying the `google_project_iam_binding` resource of terraform. I have now recovered all the users.

Now, I want to create a private service connection with GCP to assign the private IP to CloudSQL. But I am getting the below error.

> We encountered a problem while creating a connection. Required
> 'compute.globalAddresses.list' permission for 'projects/XXXXXX' Help
> Token:XXXXXXX

I have enabled/disabled all the services, IAM users having the owner access.

PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com has the editor access as well.

I got the below error while creating the private connection:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if you still have the service account, "*`service-(your-project-number)@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com`*" from IAM & Admin > Service accounts?

If not, then its possible that it has been deleted. You can [recreate this service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) by following the steps below:

A. Navigate to IAM & Admin > Service Accounts in the GCP console.
B. Create the default account *`‘service-(your-project-number)@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com’`* and assign the role **‘servicenetworking.serviceAgent’** by filtering and selecting **‘Service Networking Service Agent’** in the dropdown to select a role.
C. Once created, try to setup a private service connection again.

Or you may try to undelete the deleted service account by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating)